# Error al ejecutar el comando npm start en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Cuando ejecuto el codigo `npm start` para hacer que la app se inicie me da este error:

[image: texto en negrita]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. El error en la imagen es prácticamente ilegible; agrégala en la pregunta _como texto, con formato_, además de hacer el título de tu pregunta más específico. Lee [ask] y [por qué es bueno agregar la excepción como texto](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2873/), y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 1):

A pesar de la dificultad para leer la imagen, el problema se debe a que en la dirección donde estas ejecutando nodejs tiene un **"&"**, en tu caso en

> "...Hooks & Firebase..."

**¿Porque sucede esto?**
Nodejs al detectar un **&** en un string lo dividira en dos provocando que no se puedan encontrar los módulos, para resolver esto deberás de cambiar el nombre de la carpeta con el **&** o mover el directorio del proyecto.

Si quieres saber mas [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60912342/error-cannot-find-module-react-scripts-bin-react-scripts-js) esta un post de Stack Overflow en ingles donde tocan este mismo tema(*también con react, pero este problema ocurriría con cualquier proyecto de nodejs*). ¡Espero que te sirva, saludos!